# Blender 2.8 How to make Object single user?

Tags: objects

I go into objects and next to the object name it shows how many duplicate they are and it says "click here to make single user object" (for example I have 2 duplicates) when I click on the button it changes from 2 to 3 and doesn't make it single user???

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the mesh settings before and after you press the button? You should get a unique mesh with a unique name when you press it.